# AngularJS: ng-if outside ng-repeat breaks ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

**AngularJS Verion:** 1.3.8

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/uYFE9/4/

I've been working on a small AngularJS application, and ran into a bit of a problem. I have an `ng-repeat` on a page, which fills in the contents of a form. The amount of items in the form is defined by a dropdown bound to a model, and populated using `ng-options`. Something like:

```
<select id="testAmount" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items"></select>

<form role="form" name="testForm" ng-if="!complete">
    <div ng-repeat="i in getNumber(selectedItem.number) track by $index">
        {{$index}}
    </div>
</form>
```

`Complete` is set to false in the beginning, and hitting a `Next` button will toggle `complete` and hide the form and dropdown. A `Back` button will then toggle `complete` back, and show the form again.

The problem I'm having is with the `ng-if` on the select (and previously, I had the form wrapped in a `div` with the same `ng-if` - same problem). The `ng-repeat` no longer updates when the `select` dropdown is changed. Removing the `ng-if` on the `select` restores the `ng-repeat` to working order.

I'm wondering if there's something strange I'm doing with the nesting here, or if it's actually a bug? You can test it out on the JSFiddle linked above. The `$index` should be printed the number of times on the dropdown, but isn't.

Interestingly enough - when debugging the problem on my local machine, having FireBug open fixed the issue.

Comment: Your issue has to do with the child scope created with the ng-if and lack of dot rule. You can fix it by setting `$scope.selected.item = $scope.items[0];` and using `ng-model="selected.item"` on select and on repeat use it accordingly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs

Comment: Yup, that was the issue. I don't know why I didn't see it earlier. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of `ng-if` creating a child scope and how prototypical inheritance works with primitives. In this case, the primitive is `selectedItem` that you are setting by the `<select>`, but is actually being set on the child scope and shadows/hides the parent scope property.

In general you should always use a dot (.) with `ng-model`s:

```
$scope.selection = {selectedItem: undefined};
```

And in the View:

```
<div ng-if="!complete">
  <select ng-model="selection.selectedItem" 
          ng-options="item.name for item in items"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the problem. For some reason that didn't occur to me at all.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-if` is causing you some scoping issues (which messes with the binding).

Here is an [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bzsdtpft/) that you could use as a work around.  Essentially, this example wraps another `div` around the items that you want to end up hiding.  And then adds a `next` function so that the same scope is affected during the click that sets `complete` to `true`.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="test">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <div ng-if="!complete">
            <div>
                <label for="testAmount">Amount:</label>
                <select id="testAmount" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items"></select>
            </div>

            <form role="form" name="testForm">
                <div ng-repeat="i in getNumber(selectedItem.number) track by $index">
                    {{$index + 'hi'}}
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-default" value="Next" title="Next" ng-click="next()">Next</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div ng-if="complete">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('test', [])
.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.complete = false;

    $scope.items = [
        { name: '2', number: 2 },
        { name: '3', number: 3 },
        { name: '4', number: 4 }
    ];

    $scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[0];

    $scope.getNumber = function (number) {
        return new Array(number);
    };

    $scope.next = function() {
      $scope.complete = true;  
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with your select statement inside an ng-if the selectedItem is never getting set. If you just don't want to show that dropdown when !complete change it to an ng-show and it works fine.

```
    <div ng-show="!complete">
```

As to WHY the ng-model is not being bound inside the ng-if, I don't really know but it does make some sense in that you are trying to do a conditional bind which is a bit screwy

Comment: It's not being bound because `ng-if` (unlike `ng-show`) creates a child scope. And `selectedItem` *is* getting set - but on the child scope.